# Upper bounding the sum with hypergeometric and binomial probabilities

Tags: pr.probability, inequalities, hypergeometric-functions, lower-bounds, binomial-distribution

Could you please help me upper bound this tricky expression:

$$P(A)=\sum_{i=0}^n{\left( 1 - \dfrac{\binom kq \binom {n-k}{i-q}}{\binom {n}{i}} \right)}^I \binom ni p^i {(1-p)}^{n-i}$$.

So far I only managed to obtain a lower bound by proving $\sum_{i=0}^n{\dfrac{\binom kq \binom {n-k}{i-q}}{\binom {n}{i}}\binom ni p^i {(1-p)}^{n-i}}=\binom kq p^q {(1-p)}^{k-q}$ and applying Jensen's inequality for power function $f(x):=x^I$.

This lower bound is $P(A) \geq {\left(1-\binom kq p^q {(1-p)}^{k-q}\right)}^I$ and works okay for my needs. However, I would like to get a similar upper bound too and this is what causes the main difficulty.

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: What is $I$? Is $p$ in $[0,1]$? What are $n,k,q$?

Comment: Oh, yes, sorry. $I, n, k, q$ are natural numbers and $p$ is  in $[0,1]$.

Comment: Too many variables; not enough constraints.